# How to fix hover on links that're not working because of container?

Tags: html, css, hover

I want to have 3 columns for menu, story and description. I want to show a unique description of each story. Everything works until I put a `div` on the middle column. The same problem occurred for the right column but fixed it by adding `div` to `~ .desc`, `~ .s1-desc`, and `~ .s2-desc`. I understand why the selection doesn't work for the middle column, but I'm not sure what to implement to make what I want work. How can I hover `.s1` to make `.s1-desc` show?

Here's what I have working: (The div breaking the css has been commented in the html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .row {
            display: flex;
        }

        .sideCol {
            flex: 30%;
            margin: 10px;
            padding: 10px;
        }

        .midCol {
            flex: 40%;
            margin: 50px;
        }

        .desc, .s1-desc, .s2-desc {
            display: none;
        }

         a:not(.home):hover ~ div .desc {
            display: block;
            color: red;
        }
        
        .s1:hover ~ div .s1-desc, .s2:hover ~ div .s2-desc {
            display: block;
            color: purple;
            padding: 10px;
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="sideCol">
            <p>Menu</p>
            <a href="#">Category One</a>
            <a href="#">Category Two</a>
        </div>
        
        <!-- <div class="midCol"> this div is what breaks the scope but I need a column here -->
            <p>Selection</p>
            <a class="home" href="#">Home</a>
            <a class="s1" href="#">Story One</a>
            <a class="s2" href="#">Story Two</a>
        <!-- </div> -->
        
        <div class="sideCol">
            <p class="desc">Description</p>
            <p class="s1-desc">Desc of Story One. A Desc of Story One. Desc of Story One. A Desc of Story One. Desc of Story One.</p>
            <p class="s2-desc">Desc of Story Two. A Desc of Story Two. Desc of Story Two. A Desc of Story Two. Desc of Story Two.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's what's not working:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .row {
            display: flex;
        }

        .sideCol {
            flex: 30%;
            margin: 10px;
            padding: 10px;
        }

        .midCol {
            flex: 40%;
            margin: 50px;
        }

        .desc, .s1-desc, .s2-desc {
            display: none;
        }

         a:not(.home):hover ~ div .desc {
            display: block;
            color: red;
        }
        
        .s1:hover ~ div .s1-desc, .s2:hover ~ div .s2-desc {
            display: block;
            color: purple;
            padding: 10px;
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="sideCol">
            <p>Menu</p>
            <a href="#">Category One</a>
            <a href="#">Category Two</a>
        </div>
        
        <div class="midCol">
            <p>Selection</p>
            <a class="home" href="#">Home</a>
            <a class="s1" href="#">Story One</a>
            <a class="s2" href="#">Story Two</a>
        </div>
        
        <div class="sideCol">
            <p class="desc">Description</p>
            <p class="s1-desc">Desc of Story One. A Desc of Story One. Desc of Story One. A Desc of Story One. Desc of Story One.</p>
            <p class="s2-desc">Desc of Story Two. A Desc of Story Two. Desc of Story Two. A Desc of Story Two. Desc of Story Two.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
}

.sideCol {
  flex: 30;
  -webkit-flex: 30;
}

.summary {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 20%;
  right: 0;
  width: 30%;
  border: solid;
}

a:hover+.summary {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="sideCol">
      <p>Menu</p>
      <a href="#">Category One</a>
      <a href="#">Category Two</a>
    </div>

    <div class="midCol">
      <p>Selection</p>
      <a class="home" href="#">Home</a>
      <a class="s1" href="#">Story One</a>
      <div class="summary">
        <p>Description One</p>
      </div>
      <a class="s2" href="#">Story Two</a>
      <div class="summary">
        <p>Description Two</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="sideCol"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```